# How to Upgrade Rails to 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I Want to upgrade my Rails application properly from 3.2.12 to 4.2 ...

someone send me this link: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

at the moment I'm trying to upgrade from 3.2.12 to 4.0 ... i'm hanging on step 5.4:

```
Rails 4.0 no longer supports loading plugins from vendor/plugins. 
You must replace any plugins by extracting them to gems and adding them to your Gemfile. 
If you choose not to make them gems, you can move them into, say, lib/my_plugin/* 
and add an appropriate initializer in config/initializers/my_plugin.rb.
```

Okay thats no Problem to copy from vendor/plugins to lib ... but how do I have to set up the initializers? ...

Comment: Perhaps this [**blog article**](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins/) might be helpful.

Comment: follow http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

Comment: You're going to have to figure out what's going on with the specific plugins, and write some code -- if the plugins are in-house, or otherwise unsupported. It's not neccesarily a purely mechanical process.  In addition to the blog article recommended by spickermann, which is a good one, I wrote one [here](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/converting-a-more-complex-rails-2-3-style-plugin-to-non-deprecated-under-rails-3-2/) too. You should try to get everything to run with zero deprecation warnings in 3.2.21 (latest 3.2.x) before upgrading to 4.0, then 4.1, then 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializers are plain ruby files that get executed on startup. They live in `config/initializers`